# WPF: assign child element to property in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls, properties

Hi I want to do the following in xaml:

I have a property FocusTarget in my control class which I want to assign an UIElement from the current class. Is this possible in XAML?

```
<my:BaseControl x:Class="SectionControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    FocusTarget="myCtrl">   // this fails           
       ..       
       <my:CodeBlockControl x:Name="myCtrl" />           
       ..       
</my:BaseControl>
```

UPDATE:
I now implemented the property as dependency property but it seems that no assignment occures, although I assign it in XAML. But there is not compile nor runtime error:

in xaml:

```
    FocusTarget="{Binding ElementName=myCtrl}"
```

in cs:

```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusTargetProperty;      

    static BaseControl()
    {
        FrameworkPropertyMetadata metadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null);
        FocusTargetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FocusTarget", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(BaseControl), metadata, Validate);
   }

    public FrameworkElement FocusTarget
    {
        get { return GetValue(FocusTargetProperty)as FrameworkElement; }
        set { SetValue(FocusTargetProperty, value); }
    }
```

Comment: Could your "Validate" callback be stopping the assignment somehow? Might be worth temporarily commenting it out to see if it starts working.

Comment: no it is a method which does nothing but always returning true

Comment: I had the issue of properties not being set when I try to shortcut making a full-blown control; my custom control was derived from UIElement. Lesson: derive from Control like the manual says!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be a bunch of reasons why `{Binding ElementName=...}` doesn't work for you. It does lookup via inherited context, which propagates through visual element tree. If there's no way to walk through visual tree from binding to element it is referencing, the binding will fail. For example, if `my:CodeBlockControl` is declared inside `Resources`, or in a `ControlTemplate` of some control, or if there is a `Popup` between it and root (including implicit one, such as e.g. introduced by `ContextMenu`), this is what will happen.

Unfortunately, there's no general-purpose way to reference any other element from the same XAML directly. There will be in .NET 4.0 `XamlReader`, though it will still be disabled for BAML (and, consequently, for WPF). One alternative is to use resources and `{StaticResource}` instead:

```
<my:BaseControl x:Class="SectionControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    FocusTarget="{StaticResource myCtrl}">

  <my:BaseControl.Resources>
    <my:CodeBlockControl x:Key="myCtrl" />
  </my:BaseControl.Resources>

  ...
  <!-- where it originally was -->
  <StaticResource ResourceKey="myCtrl"/>
  ...

</my:BaseControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure FocusTarget is a dependency property, and bind your target control using an element binding:

```
<my:BaseControl x:Class="SectionControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    FocusTarget="{Binding ElementName=myCtrl}">
    ..
    <my:CodeBlockControl x:Name="myCtrl" />
    ..
```

Comment: I tried it but my property values are null, although assigned in the xaml code, even the PropertyChangedCallback doesn't fire. What could gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Binding syntax is of the form : Target = "{Binding Source}"

It is required by the framework that Target is always a dependency property, while source can just be a plain old CLR property.

Matt Hamilton's answer should work.

Comment: When dealing with binding issues, I generally search through the Output window to find any binding errors. They all start with System.Windows.DataError. So, are there any errors in the Output window?